# Как узнать, что сайт тормозит из-за провайдеров, ограничивающих доступ к нему, в следствие отмены "сетевого нейтралитета"?

Tags: linux, сеть, веб-сервер, провайдер

В связи с недавними новостями из-за океана [Федеральная комиссия по связи США отменила правило «сетевого нейтралитета»](https://www.securitylab.ru/news/490289.php), возникает вопрос, а можно ли каким-либо техническим образом узнать (проверить), что тот или иной сайт "тормозит" как раз таки в следствие политики данного провайдера из США?

Comment: А есть хоть один провайдер, который так делает?

Comment: А если доступ ограничен, то канал какбэ шире? Конкурентов на контент меньше? Или ресурс там?